# Cartier divisor that is not a difference of two effective Cartier divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

Note: There are [already](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992498/example-of-a-cartier-divisor-that-cannot-be-written-as-the-difference-of-effecti) [several](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363117/can-effective-divisors-generate-all-cartier-divisors?noredirect=1&lq=1) [related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173287/picard-group-generated-by-effective-divisors-counterexample) questions, without any definite answer.

I want to find an example of a Noetherian integral scheme $X$ which contains a Cartier divisor that is not linearly equivalent to a difference of two effective Cartier divisors. It will be great if $X$ is a variety.

[This](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02FB) stack project exercise suggests a [proper variety that is not projective](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02AS). However, I cannot prove why this is a counterexample. It is not hard to show that $X$ does not have any nontrivial effective Cartier divisor. Hence it is enough to find an example of a nontrivial Cartier divisor, or a nontrivial line bundle, on $X$, but it is hard to construct such an example.

Comment: OK,I think your notion of a Cartier divisor is different from Hartshorne's definition: a Cartier divisor on a variety $X$ is an element of $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}^*/\mathcal{O}^*)$ where $\mathcal{K}$ is the sheaf of rational functions. For a variety of positive dimension, this is always very big.

Comment: Sorry. I mean "Cartier divisor up to linear equivalence". Fixed!

Comment: The Picard group of the example is nontrivial as it equals $k^*$. The Picard group of a variety is equal to the group of Cartier divisors up to rational equivalence.

Comment: How can I calculate that Picard group of the example?

Comment: Take a few days to think about it. Fitst do some easier examples of glueings. Etc, etc.

Comment: OK, I have one plausible approach. Let $\pi:\mathbb{P}_k^3\to X$ be the map. Then this induces a morphism of sheaves $O_X^\times\to \pi_\ast O_{\mathbb{P}_k^3}^\times$. Since $\pi$ is finite, we can calculate their stalk (at least in the etale topology). Based on this calculation, I think this is injective, and the cokernel is $i_\ast O_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}^\times$, where $i$ is the inclusion of "bad locus". Then I think the LES of (etale) cohomology associated to this SES can solve the problem... Is this the right way to do this?